# How to change Rails 4.2.4 app config to use Production db instead of Development

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: pgtest_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: pgtest_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: pgtest_production
  username: pgtest
  password: <%= ENV['PGTEST_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I have deployed my rails app to Digital Ocean but issue is it tries to access the developement database instead of production although live rails app use production database . Production database is already exist still shows `Fatal_error:development database not found` in rails console. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **`RAILS_ENV`** to **`production`** and then start the **`rails console`**.

Try this command

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

or

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```